# Microsoft Live custom C# REST API error 415

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

I'm trying to get data from the Microsoft Live API. However, when I try to get the access_token, I instead get a 415(Unsupported Media Type) error message. I have looked pretty much everywhere, but I can't find any answer (that worked for me).

Here is my (partial) code that tries to get the token (dataToWrite is cut-up for readability, it's one line in the actual code):

```
WebRequest request;
request = WebRequest.Create("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var dataToWrite = "code=[code]&
  client_id=[client_id]&
  client_secret=[client_secret]&
  redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&
  grant_type=authorization_code";

var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToWrite);
request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
dataStream.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Where the '[]' are:

- [code] is a string, given by Microsoft after user logs in (this part of the code works);
- [client_id] is a string, given by Microsoft, representing my client id;
- [client_secret] is a string, given by Microsoft, representing my client secret;
- [redirect_uri] is the URL of the site's return location (same as the URL used in the code for the user consent(see [code]))

According to the manual of Microsoft Live API(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx) this should work. However, the documentation isn't very detailed.

Does anyone know why I keep getting the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm an idiot...

It does work after all. I did another request after this one. And that one failed because I did not include the parameters there.